# Why doesn't 'which ruby' output anything?

Tags: debian, ruby

On Debian 6, I uninstalled Ruby 1.8 and installed 1.9.1. Now if I run `which ruby` it doesn't output anything. Why can't it find ruby anymore?

Comment: How did you install 1.9.1? From a package? From a tarball? From source?

Comment: which command looks up $PATH variable to search the executable binary/ies. So, you need to know the path where you had installed your ruby package and update the path into regular $PATH variable like in your shell-rc files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for it:

```
find / -name ruby 2> /dev/null
```

If you get a positive location, make sure that the directory is in your `$PATH`. If you don't get any output, your Ruby installation didn't go as planned.